# What is the unit of measurement in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Let's say I have a mesh. And want to position it in 3D using the following:

```
mesh.position.set(5, 5, 5);
```

What are those numbers? I'm sure it isn't 5 pixels for x. For example:

```
mesh.position.x
```

Would indeed return 5, but this is where things get tricky.

I'm using the raycaster in order to know where the mouse is which is either Normalized Coordinate System or Pixel using the following:

```
function onMouseMove(event){ // Calculate mouse movements
    // Normalized Coordinate System
    mouse.ncs.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.ncs.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    // Pixel coordinates
    mouse.p.x = event.clientX;
    mouse.p.y = event.clientY;            
};
```

But how would I say 5 equal this amount of pixels? Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Raycaster.setFromCamera()` you must use normalized coordinates, so from `[-1, 1]`, which it looks like you're already converting to. The units of measurement of the 3D world don't matter, the ray will calculate whether it's being intersected by your object or not. Try following [this example in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster).

To answer your original question, Three.js and WebGL at large are natively "unitless". You can pretend the units are in inches, meters, whatever you want them to be. The only instance where units matter is with `THREE.CSS3DRenderer`, where units are a mix of pixels and unitless because you're dealing with HTML elements.

Comment: This solved my problem actually. I just needed to do a mouse over.

Comment: @konkret Glad to hear! If the answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it, or vote on it so it can also help others!

Comment: It is done. Thanks!